# Table-like design using div tags and css

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

I'm pretty new to html and css so perhaps this is a crazy easy question to answer, and if so, sorry for that.

I did some research on how to properly set up a page so that it's responsive. Originally I had used a table to arrange images and commentary on one of my web pages. (I left that one up here http://www.maddielabstudio.com/artwork-table for reference.) I then figured out that it wasn't showing up properly on my phone. After researching a bit, I came to the conclusion that I probably shouldn't have used a table in the first place and that div tags and CSS were a better solution.

I got the images to be where I want them and to scale properly with a change in screen size. However, I'm not sure how to get the commentary to be on the right of the images and centered vertically on the image. Ideally, if the screen gets below a certain size, I'd then like the commentary to move below the image. Here is what I have so far in my attempt to set this up: www.maddielabstudio.com/artwork. Basically, I want it to look like the page I made with a table, but to be responsive, scale the images down when necessary, and move the commentary below the image when the screen in phone sized.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend looking into responsive grid systems for CSS, such as Skeleton (http://www.getskeleton.com). They're super easy to use, and will do a lot of the legwork for you!

Also - try this for scaling your images:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I actually figured out the `code`img { max-width: 100%:} `code` already, thanks. And that skeleton thing looks pretty awesome. I'll have to give it a try.

Comment: how familiar are you with Skeleton? I think this may be a total newbie question, but how do I get my child theme to recognize the skeleton.css file? It works if I copy and paste it into my style.css file, but I have a feeling that is not the best way to go about doing it.

Answer (score 1):

To get the commentary on the right side of your images, this should work:

Remove `float:left` and add `display:inline-block` to the `.artwork` style.
Add `display:inline-block` to the `.commentary` style.

As for the vertical align, I think you could set `vertical-align:middle` for those span tags.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It worked to get the commentary to the right, but it doesn't do anything for moving the commentary below the images on a smaller screen. I may resort to it if I can't find another good solution.